# MIcrosoft word - space between table and title

Tags: microsoft-word, line-spacing

I am trying to add a title to the top of a table but do what I may, there is always a substantial space between the table and its title. I changed spacing, changed spacing in paragraph options etc. Nothing seems to be working.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'ts almost imposible to know from a picture, try showing formatting marks: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Show-or-hide-formatting-marks-c2d8a607-5646-4165-8b08-bd68f9d172a0

Comment: Post your word file, not a screen copy, so we can look at details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Home tab of Word, in the Paragraph group, there is button with an icon on it that looks kind of like this ¶. It's called a Pilcrow. Click it and all hidden characters in the document will display. Check for any extra blank paragraphs or Continuous Section Breaks. Get rid of anything that shouldn't be there.

Check the Paragraph formatting of the Title and of the paragraph where the table is inserted on. Make sure there aren't any Points Before or After specified.

Finally, open the Page Setup dialog. You can do this from the Layout tab. Open Margins and select Custom Margins. The Margins dialog has 3 tabs. Choose the Layout one and on this dialog is a setting for Vertical Alignment. Make sure it is set for Top and not Center.

Hope this helps